# Как редактировать скрытый код?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Суть проблемы:
Скачал готовый слайдер на jQuery, там в скрытом коде прописано, чтобы картинки были 800х350. Хочу вставить туда картинки 960х400, и я могу сделать это в браузере, но код, который виден в браузере, не виден в самом файле html.
Почему его не видно и как его отредактировать в файле?

Comment: Напишите, какой именно слайдер вы скачали, у готовых слайдеров обычно есть возможность  задать размеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, видимо, скачали демо-страницу этого слайдера. То, что вы видите в браузере, - результат работы скрипта слайдера. Это скрипт прописывает размеры прямо в HTML-код во время своей работы, поэтому в браузере вы это видите, а в самом HTML-файле - нет. 
Размеры указываются либо в CSS-стилях, либо в Javascript-файле, который инициализирует слайдер.

Comment: Спасибо, все понял.